# Problem with CSS display: Grid (grid-template-areas)

Tags: css, css-grid

So I want to make a table using CSS-Grid, but it isn't working out the way the elements are displayed, it should be a 6x6 box with the two tables being only one header and one row each.

here is a imagem of the error: https://i.stack.imgur.com/4jS63.jpg

What I want is: First table should be like:

```
Nome     Espécie      Raça         Sexo       Idade     Descrição
Teto      Rara      Céu Azul     Masculino     19        Fashion
```

Second table should be like:

```
Nome     Espécie      Raça         Sexo       Idade     Descrição
Wiu      Pitbull      Limão      Masculino     18         Frio
```

Nome, Espécie, Raça, Sexo, Idade and Descrição are the headers.

```css
body {
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom right, yellow, #b3ecff, #cc66ff);
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
}

.item1 {
  grid-area: item1;
}

.item3 {
  grid-area: item3;
}

.item5 {
  grid-area: item5;
}

.button1 {
  grid-area: button1;
}

.headernome1 {
  grid-area: headernome1;
}

.headernome2 {
  grid-area: headernome2;
}

.headerespecie1 {
  grid-area: headerespecie1;
}

.headerespecie2 {
  grid-area: headerespecie2;
}

.headerraca1 {
  grid-area: headerraca1;
}

.headerraca2 {
  grid-area: headerraca2;
}

.headersexo1 {
  grid-area: headersexo1;
}

.headersexo2 {
  grid-area: headersexo2;
}

.headeridade1 {
  grid-area: headeridade1;
}

.headeridade2 {
  grid-area: headeridade2;
}

.headerdescricao1 {
  grid-area: headerdescricao1;
}

.headerdescricao2 {
  grid-area: headerdescricao2;
}

.celnome1 {
  grid-area: celnome1;
}

.celnome2 {
  grid-area: celnome2;
}

.celespecie1 {
  grid-area: celespecie1;
}

.celespecie2 {
  grid-area: celespecie2;
}

.celraca1 {
  grid-area: celraca1;
}

.celraca2 {
  grid-area: celraca2;
}

.celsexo1 {
  grid-area: celsexo1;
}

.celsexo2 {
  grid-area: celsexo2;
}

.celidade1 {
  grid-area: celidade1;
}

.celidade2 {
  grid-area: celidade2;
}

.celdescricao1 {
  grid-area: celdescricao1;
}

.celdescricao2 {
  grid-area: celdescricao2;
}

.item2 {
  grid-area: item2;
}

.item4 {
  grid-area: item4;
}

.item6 {
  grid-area: item6;
}

.button2 {
  grid-area: button2;
}

.grid-container {
  display: grid;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #FFFFD2, #AA96DA, #FFFFD2);
  padding: 5px;
  grid-template-areas: "item1 item1 item1 item1 item1 item1" "item3 item3 item3 item3 item3 item3" "item5 item5 item5 item5 item5 item5" "headernome1 headerespecie1 headerraca1 headersexo1 headeridade1 headerdescricao1" "celnome1 celespecie1 celraca1 celsexo1 celidade1 celdescricao1" "button1 button1 button1 button1 button1 button1" "item2''item2 item2 item2 item2 item2" "item4 item4 item4 item4 item4 item4" "item6 item6 item6 item6 item6 item6" "headernome2 headerespecie2 headerraca2 headersexo2 headeridade2 headerdescricao2" "celnome2 celespecie2 celraca2 celsexo2 celidade2 celdescricao2" "button2 button2 button2 button2 button2 button2";
}

.grid-container>div {
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom right, yellow, #b3ecff, #cc66ff);
  text-align: center;
  padding: 5px 0;
  font-size: 30px;
}

.caixa {
  box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom right, yellow, #b3ecff, #cc66ff);
  width: 85%;
  border: 2px solid #99ccff;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
</head>

<body>
  <center>
    <div class='caixa'>
      <?php
  $codigo = 1;
  $dois = 2;
  echo "<div class='grid-container'>";
  echo "<div class='item1'>" . 'Foto do Pet' . "</div>";
  echo "<div class='item2'>" . 'Foto do Pet' . "</div>";
  echo "<div class='item3'>" . "<input form='editfoto' type='file' name='foto$codigo' accept='image/*'>" . "</div>";
  echo "<div class='item4'>" . "<input form='editfoto' type='file' name='foto$dois' accept='image/*'>" . "</div>";
  echo "<div class='item5'>"; "<img name='imagem$codigo' id='NOVOimagem$codigo' src='https://www.w3schools.com/images/w3schools_green.jpg' width=300 height=320 />";"</div>";
  echo "<div class='item6'>"; "<img name='imagem$dois' id='NOVOimagem$dois' src='https://www.w3schools.com/images/w3schools_green.jpg' width=300 height=320 />";"</div>";
  echo "<div class='button$codigo'>;<button type='button' id='botao_salvar' onclick='salvar_registro($codigo)'>" . 'Salvar' . "</button>;</div>";
  echo "<div class='button$dois'>;<button type='button' id='botao_salvar' onclick='salvar_registro($dois)'>" . 'Salvar' . "</button>;</div>";
  echo "<div class='headernome$codigo'>" . 'Nome' . "</div>";
  echo "<div class='headerespecie$codigo'>". 'Espécie' ."</div>";
  echo "<div class='headerraca$codigo'>". 'Raça' ."</div>";
  echo "<div class='headersexo$codigo'>". 'Sexo' ."</div>";
  echo "<div class='headeridade$codigo'>". 'Idade' ."</div>";
  echo "<div class='headerdescricao$codigo'>". 'Descrição' ."</div>";
  echo "<div class='headernome$dois'>" . 'Nome' . "</div>";
  echo "<div class='headerespecie$dois'>". 'Espécie' ."</div>";
  echo "<div class='headerraca$dois'>". 'Raça' ."</div>";
  echo "<div class='headersexo$dois'>". 'Sexo' ."</div>";
  echo "<div class='headeridade$dois'>". 'Idade' ."</div>";
  echo "<div class='headerdescricao$dois'>". 'Descrição' ."</div>";
  
  echo "<div class='celnome$codigo'>" . 'Teto' . "</div>";
  echo "<div class='celespecie$codigo'>". 'Rara' ."</div>";
  echo "<div class='celraca$codigo'>". 'Céu Azul' ."</div>";
  echo "<div class='celsexo$codigo'>". 'Masculino' ."</div>";
  echo "<div class='celidade$codigo'>". '19' ."</div>";
  echo "<div class='celdescricao$codigo'>". 'Fashion' ."</div>";
  echo "<div class='celnome$dois'>" . 'Wiu' . "</div>";
  echo "<div class='celespecie$dois'>". 'Pitbull' ."</div>";
  echo "<div class='celraca$dois'>". 'Limão' ."</div>";
  echo "<div class='celsexo$dois'>". 'Masculino' ."</div>";
  echo "<div class='celidade$dois'>". '18' ."</div>";
  echo "<div class='celdescricao$dois'>". 'Frio' ."</div>";
  ?>
    </div>
    </div>
  </center>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: You have a typo, a singly quote instead of a double quote ar the end of line 3 of the template area definition.

Comment: @AHaworth true, I changed here but it isn't working yet

Comment: Could you therefore correct the code in the question and create a runnable snippet which shows the problem. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: i will do it, just a moment

Comment: just added the snippet

Comment: A couple of suggestions. Use your browser dev tools inspect facility to look to see exactly what CSS has been created by your PHP. Look carefully at your PHP. What will 'foto$codigo' output for example? You need to concatenate the string 'foto' with the variable $codigo. This turns out to be an error in the way PHP is being used, but you have not tagged the question with php.

Comment: it would be "foto1", I really have no idea, prob I am going to try something different if I am not able to disguise what is wrong, thanks

Comment: Don't you need to concatenate them, using .